# knitr: Use an inline expression in fig.cap chunk option

Tags: knitr

My question is about the knitr option fig.cap, when using LaTeX. Is it possible to include an \rinline or \Sexpr
in the fig.cap character string?

For example, I would like to have something like (I'm using an .Rtex file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%% begin.rcode fig.cap="x is \\rinline{x}"
% x <- 5
% p <- seq(0,5)
% q <- x*p
% plot(p,q)
%% end.rcode
\end{document}
```

I'd really like for that chunk to produce a plot in my .tex document, with a caption reading "x is 5". Instead, it throws an "undefined control sequence" error on pdflatex compilation.

If I don't escape the rinline (i.e. use just \rinline{x}), then it compiles, but the caption is "x is inlinex".

Is what I'm asking possible?

This is my first SO question (used the answers here many times, though. Thanks!), so I'd appreciate any feedback on how to ask better questions.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fig.cap` is evaluated as an R expression, so instead of using `\rinline` (and thus having the caption again parsed by `knitr`), you can just create the caption string in R.

```
%% begin.rcode fig.cap=paste("x is", x)
```

but because `fig.cap` is evaluated *before* `x` is created by default, you will need to postpone the evaluation of `fig.cap`; to do that, you can include a chunk like this in the beginning of your document:

```
%% begin.rcode setup, include=FALSE
%% opts_knit$set(eval.after = 'fig.cap')
%% end.rcode
```

It specifies `fig.cap` to be evaluated after the code chunk is evaluated, i.e. when `x` is available for you to use in the figure caption. See [`eval.after` in the documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

The other way to do this is to create `x` in a *previous* chunk, and use `fig.cap=paste("x is", x)` in the *next* chunk.

Comment: Actually I have been thinking about this problem - I think it is reasonable to make chunk options like `fig.cap` into the `eval.after` option by default because they are only used after a chunk.

Comment: That's great; eval.after is exactly what I was looking for! I'm embarrassed I hadn't found it myself-RTFM I guess. Thanks guys!

Comment: @user2225161 No problem; as I said, I may want this to happen by default instead of being set manually; `eval.after` is kind of awkward...

Comment: @Yihui Thank you for completing my answer. I had forgotten about setting the `eval.after` because I have it set in my default template just so I don't have to remember it every time.

Comment: @Yihui I agree that would be a better default. Did you think of a downside, or just haven't gotten around to this?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I cannot think of a downside. You may file a feature request to https://github.com/yihui/knitr